# How to toggle active class in two button and hide div using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my case, My button1 is active by default so my form1 is shown by default too and I want to switch the two forms by clicking the button1 and button2. How can we accomplish that using jQuery.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-light activate-form active-btn">
  button 1 = show form1
</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-light activate-form">
  button 2 = show form2
</button>

<form id="normal-user-form" class="custom-register">form1</form>
<form id="business-user-form" class="custom-register">form2</form>

<script>
  $(function() {
    $(".activate-form").click(function() {
        
        $(".activate-form").removeClass("active-btn");
        
        $(this).addClass("active-btn");
    });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use a `.is-active` (with the appropriate CSS) for both your buttons and forms
- Cache your forms in a variable
- Use the `data-*` attribute (i.e: `data-target` in the example below) to store the desired selector you want to target on click

```js
jQuery(($) => {

  const $actForms = $(".custom-register");
  const $actFormsBtns = $(".activate-form");

  $actFormsBtns.on("click", function() {
    $actFormsBtns.add($actForms).removeClass("is-active");
    $(this).add($(this.dataset.target)).addClass("is-active");
  });
  
});
```

```css
.activate-form.is-active { background: #0bf; }

.custom-register            { display: none; }
.custom-register.is-active { display: block; }
```

```html
<button type="button" data-target="#normal-user-form" class="btn btn-light activate-form is-active" >form1</button>
<button type="button" data-target="#business-user-form" class="btn btn-light activate-form" data-target="">form2</button>

<form id="normal-user-form" class="custom-register is-active">form1</form>
<form id="business-user-form" class="custom-register">form2</form>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63626198/how-can-i-prevent-express-ejs-layouts-from-wrapping-my-other-page

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you mean correctly, you're looking for something like this:

```js
$(function() {
  $(".activate-form").click(function() {
      $(".activate-form").removeClass("active-btn");

      var formId = $(this).addClass("active-btn").data('target');
      
      $("form").removeClass("active-btn");
      $(formId).addClass("active-btn");
  });
});
```

```css
.active-btn {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-light activate-form active-btn" data-target="#normal-user-form">
  button 1 = show form1
</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-light activate-form" data-target="#business-user-form">
  button 2 = show form2
</button>

<form id="normal-user-form" class="custom-register active-btn">form1</form>
<form id="business-user-form" class="custom-register">form2</form>
```

You can try to add `data-target` attribute inside the `<button>` tag to refer the form id.

Comment: Use rather a `.is-active` for both forms and buttons.

Comment: Also, never just use `$("form")`. This could break pretty soon.