# How can I prevent express-ejs-layouts for wrapping my other page?

Tags: node.js, layout, ejs

I'm finding a page layout for node.js like [laravel php](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/templates) have their Template for layout and it is perfect. I want to achieve it here in node.js and finally found this [express-ejs-layouts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-ejs-layouts) but there is a problem in it that I cant see in their documentation the layout will wrap all of my pages specially my signin and signup page which have a different header and footer. How can we prevent express-ejs-layouts from wrapping my other page?

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const path = require('path');
const multer = require('multer');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mysql = require('mysql');
const app = express();
const server = require('http').createServer(app);
const expressLayouts = require('express-ejs-layouts');

// Set Database Connection
const connection=mysql.createConnection({
    host:'localhost',
    user:'root',
    password:'',
    database:'project_101'
});

connection.connect(function(error){
    if(!!error) console.log(error);
    else console.log('Database Connected!');
});

app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.static('assets'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());       
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(expressLayouts);

app.get('/',(req, res) => {
    let sql = "SELECT * FROM uploads";
    let query = connection.query(sql, (err, rows) => {
        if(err) throw err;
        res.render('index');
    });
});

app.get('/signup', (req, res) => {
    res.render('signup');
});

app.get('/signin', (req, res) => {
    res.render('signin');
});

app.get('/unknown-user', (req, res) => {
    res.render('unknown-user');
});

app.get('/profile', (req, res) => {
    res.render('profile');
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

// Server Listening
server.listen(port, function () {
    console.log('Server successfully running at: -',port);
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally got the solution for the problem [express-ejs-layouts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-ejs-layouts)

```
const express = require('express');
const expressLayouts = require('express-ejs-layouts');

app.use(expressLayouts);
```

> You just need to declare your page as a layout and set it to false.

```
app.set("layout signin", false);
```

> and render the page together with the layout.

```
app.get('/signin', (req, res) => {
    res.render('signin', { layout: 'signin' });
});
```

ez fix ⚡️

Comment: Yeah, thought you wet trying to bypass it. Glad you got it working.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils Thanks ❤️ I just want to disable the layout to my other pages.

Answer (score 1):

You can bypass the template by [sending the file back](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.sendFile).

```
res.sendFile(path, options, fn);
```

`options` and `fn` are optional.

Comment: I still don't get it. sorry :(

Comment: It's just sending a file directly so `path` is the path to the file. Try to swap out the `res.render` call in your sign up with a call to `res.sendFile` and pass it the absolute path to the sign up file and drop the `options` and `fn` args and see if you can get that working @frustrated-dev.

Comment: If it's an html page it should render in the browser @frustrated-dev.

Comment: Im using ejs file extension

Comment: @frustrated, that makes sense. So are you really looking for a way to specify different templates based on the route or bypassing it all together?